# How to you become a ROOT Shell user?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, shell

So I am rooted and used a root checker to give me some good information about my device. I noticed when it gave me info about my root it told me that I was a "non-root" shell user. [image: non-root shell]

So what does this mean? Can I possibly make it to where I AM a root shell user? I am a very curious person. ANY information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a stock ROM or a custom ROM?

In the stock ROM you would edit the build.prop and change the entry for `ro.secure=1` to `ro.secure=0` and reboot.

In most custom ROMs, and some stock ROMs, there is an entry in Developer Options called "Root access" and by default it is set to Apps only, you should be able to  change it to Apps and ADB.

There is also an app called [adb Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd) by Chainfire (the author of SuperSU) which can allow adb shell su access.

BTW, this information is easily accessible via Google, and the previous question here at [Why can't I get root access from shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40059/why-cant-i-get-root-access-from-shell)

Comment: @RyanNoles Great... Please accept and upvote my answer if you found it useful, that is how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Comment: @RyanNoles You are the question asker, you should be able to accept the answer (the check mark) even if you can't upvote it.

Comment: Aww got it lol. THANKS!  I AM A ROOT SHELL USER! LOL