# Why does "adb root" do nothing?

Tags: adb, root-access, usb-debugging

I have a OnePlus 6T. It is rooted by TWRP and Magisk. I have set `ro.debuggable` to `1`. But when I type `adb root` it does this:

```
C:\Users\ituser> adb root

C:\Users\ituser> adb remount
Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.
```

[image]

I cannot even use `adb pull` on system files.

Comment: I wonder it doesn't throw an error message. To my knowledge, `adb root` doesn't work on "production builds" (like stock ROMs, even if rooted). So unless you have a "developer ROM", chances this does anything are quite low.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On production — `user` build of a ROM — you can't start `adbd` as root unless ROM or at least `adbd` binary is rebuilt with required modifications. Reason is the `ALLOW_ADBD_ROOT` build flag <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/daemon/main.cpp#63), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/Android.mk#350))</sup>.
That's why [adbd Insecure](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590) was developed, which replaced the `adbd` binary with a modified one.

On a `userdebug` or `eng` build (or with insecure `adbd` binary extracted from any of these build types):

- If `ro.secure=0`, `adbd` runs as root when enabled from Settings (Developer Options) <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/daemon/main.cpp#78))</sup>. However `adb root` won't work <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/services.cpp#81))</sup>.
- If `ro.debuggable=1`, `adb root` will restart `adbd` as root <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/services.cpp#87), [6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/daemon/main.cpp#81))</sup>.

However `adbd` can be built from modified source code to skip all these checks. Additionally SELinux should also be taken care of, if in `enforcing` mode. `adbd` must be allowed to run in *unrestricted* superuser context: `u:r:su:s0` <sup>([7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/rootdir/init.usb.rc#15), [8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/private/su.te#19))</sup>, which isn't the case for `user` builds <sup>([9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/public/su.te#8), [10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/private/adbd.te#12), [11](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/private/adbd.te#144))</sup>. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526) for more details.

Android properties can be overwritten using `/data/local.prop` on `userdebug`/`eng` builds i.e. if `ALLOW_LOCAL_PROP_OVERRIDE` build flag is set <sup>([12](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/init/property_service.cpp#696), [13](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/init/Android.mk#9))</sup>. But this doesn't work for `ro.*` properties <sup>([14](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/init/property_service.cpp#150))</sup> and same is true for `setprop` commandline tool. However `default.prop` / `prop.default` file — which could be located under multiple possible locations depending on the device build configurations <sup>([15](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/init/property_service.cpp#680))</sup> — can be modified to change read-only properties (if not already set from some other property file or `*.rc` file). If the file is in ramdisk, `boot.img` needs to be modified.

Magisk's [resetprop](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/details.html#resetprop) tool can reset the read-only properties even if they are already set. `ro.secure` and `ro.debuggable` both may have possibly been changed as a part of MagiskHide policy <sup>([16](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/v19.3/native/jni/magiskhide/hide_policy.cpp#L25))</sup>, which you can revert back to allow `adbd` run as root.

Another related property is `ro.adb.secure`, which controls public key authentification. By setting `ro.adb.secure=0` on `userdebug`/`eng` builds, authentification is skipped (no `device unauthorized` message ever) <sup>([17](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/daemon/main.cpp#186), [18](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/Android.mk#346), [19](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/d5fcafaf41f8ec90986c813f75ec78402096af2d))</sup>; related: [Storage location of “adb_keys”](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219320/218526).

Comment: As an added info, the type of build of the rom can be found looking at `ro.build.type`