# TWRP can't access internal or SD storage (0MB) after crash+bootloop on LG G3 D855

Tags: twrp, boot-loop

After a random system crash my rooted LG G3 (D855) fails to boot into android (Android 10, Lineage OS, boot loop). As I have a recent backup on my SD card, I'm trying to restore to that in TWRP (3.4.0.0) but here's the problem - I can't change storage to the SD card where the backup or any other files are - TWRP shows "0MB" both for Internal Storage as well as for Micro SD Card.

I followed some guides suggesting to Wipe and Format data, but nothing seems to help.
I never set up any encryption, my lock screen was set to simple swype, no pin, etc.

My SD card, when connected to the PC, works fine, all backups, ROMs etc are still there, but I can't access any of it in TWRP.

I don't care about any data or installed apps, just want to access my SD card in TWRP to run Restore from Backup or at least reinstall ROM.

Comment: Be aware TWRP backup (<3.4.0) does [not include](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200713) Internal Storage, you will lose all your Pictures, WhatsApp Media and Downloads. you can mount your MicroSD Card manually. *adb pull /tmp/recovery.log* and check the paths, then run the [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) command from terminal, for example *'mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /external_sd'* (if your device has just mount issues but no problem with encryption you can do it for userdata partition too, see [example](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224440))

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I connected the phone and in TWRP activated Advanced->ADB Sideload. Now from Command Prompts in Windows 10 I'm executing "adb devices" which returns "List of devices attached LGD8559819802f  sideload", so it seems the phone is recognized. Though when I try "adb pull /tmp/recovery.log" it returns "adb: error: connect failed: closed".

Comment: do not open sideload. adb is working on TWRP with root access