# Cannot Mount userdata partition on Android 11

Tags: file-system, encryption, mount, android-11

I have pulled a block of encrypted userdata partition ".img" and trying to mount it on unecnrypted device (same device with encryption set to off). My device is rooted.

My userdata is mounted as ext4: -
**/dev/block/dm-7 on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,noauto_da_alloc,resuid=10010,resgid=1065,errors=panic)**

I have tried these steps

1. Pulled the block on local system using adb pull - userdata_block.img
2. mounted the block on an unencrypted device over CIFS using busybox mount command - userdata_block is virtually present on /sdcard/temp/userdata_block.img
3. Want to mount this img file on device to check the directory status on Android 11 if all the directories are encrypted or not.

**/system/bin/losetup /dev/block/loop2 /sdcard/temp/userdata_block.img**

**/system/bin/mount -o ro /dev/block/loop2  /sdcard/dummy**

Getting below error on Android 11, same command works fine on Android 10.

> mount: /dev/block/loop2: need -t

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `mount: /dev/block/loop2: need -t`. So did you give `-t ext4`?

Comment: yes it says Invalid argument

Comment: are you sure you have pulled /dev/block/dm-7?

Comment: yes and redirected to an img file

Comment: try busybox mount instead. try loop,ro,noexec,noload,noatime. double check userdata_block.img is [ext4](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224440) with xxd/hexdump. make sure file size (kb) matches dm-7 in /proc/partitions (sdcard must not fat32)