# Getting adb root: I did unpack and repack the boot img yet adb root doesn't work

Tags: adb, rooting, root-access, builds

my android is a Marshmallow 6.0.1 (EDIT: It is Samsung!) I just unpacked the boot.img and edited the build.prop by setting:

```
ro.secure=0
ro.debuggable=1
ro.adb.secure=0
```

repacket it, flashed it and everything is in it's place.

I no longer get the `adbd cannot run as root in production builds error`

BUT If I run adb root I get the `restarting adb as root` and nothing happens afterwards.

Can't `adb remount` because `Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.`

what else do I need to change?

EDIT: I just ran `adb root` again and this time the phone disconnected the USB:

```
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
error: write failure during connection: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "adb root" does nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213116/why-adb-root-does-nothing)

Comment: it's selinux issue

Comment: @IrfanLatif not interely I need to know how to inject an unrestricted context on the phone policy