# Accessing a phone after factory resetting it with adb

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, factory-reset

I have a smartphone running Android 6.0.1. The screen is broken and unresponsive so I control the phone using adb and scrcpy, but to run adb I had to turn on "USB debugging" from "Developer options". I want to know that whether after factory resetting(using adb) will I still be able to access the phone with adb? Since the "USB debugging" option would get turned off after a factory reset, would I still be able to access the phone using adb?

Comment: i think you gave the answer in your question already. what you can do is permantly enable adb (and disable the RSA authorization) by flashing modified boot or system, that will survive factory reset. depending on device there are several flash methods. unlocked bootloader is required for flashing via fastboot, therefore the more important you should enable OEM unlocking in developer options (if available) as long as you still have access via scrcpy

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116

Answer (score 1):

You won't have USB debugguing after a factory reset.
Perhaps you could tweak a custom rom to do so, i never tryed myself, but ie TWRP recovery have adb enabled by default.