# My Android phone does not start - how to isolate hardware issue?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot

I use Moto G6 ALI with a custom ROM Pixel Experience running Android 11. So far so good and I was using this setup for almost two weeks as my daily use phone.

Today suddenly the phone froze when opening Whatsapp. No further response on the screen was observed. I had to restart the phone by pressing the power button for more than 5 seconds. Since I have unlocked by bootloader several years ago, I saw the boot locker unlocked warning. This usually stays for 5 seconds and then after I usually the boot animation.  But this time there is no movement beyond the unlock warning.

I had flashed TWRP recovery and tried booting with it by pressing Vol-Down+Power button and then choosing "Recovery".  The phone started the recovery mode but stuck with TWRP logo.

I then restarted to bootloader and gave the command "fastboot devices" and my device was recognised. So I downloaded the 64bit version of the recovery image and temporarily booted with the command "fastboot boot mali.img".  This too stuck at the same point.  Any clues on how to go ahead?

Comment: thanks, @alecxs, I am not worried about the user data as I have a back up of all app data and all that I am worried about is to make use of the phone. An Interim update: Ran fastboot erase cache
fastboot erase userdata - boot loop and running some script in recovery - TWRP
fastboot boot 1\malix64.img - boot loop again. Yet to check further.

Comment: Thanks @alexcs the two format commands restored the device; I was able to boot into PE11 well. Of course my apps and files and data are lost, but I am not worried as I can restore them. I have my device useful again. Can you please remove these comments and post as an answer so that I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: To be precise, I had further issues in booting to PE11. All wiping through TWRP did not succeed. Since I have PE11 install ZIP in my SDCard, I initiated the installation which went smoothly and I have a fresh working device now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device received update recently which was already scheduled waiting on reboot, the instruction is placed in `/cache/recovery/command` TWRP may stuck on that instruction. this can be cleared by formatting cache partition

[TWRP Commandline Guide](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html)
If device stuck on TWRP splash screen you still might have command line access via `adb`. Note daemon has 30 second delay on start, `adbd` is not ready when TWRP is boot-looping

```
adb shell format cache
```

or manually if partition is not in fstab

```
adb shell
find /dev/block -name by-name
mke2fs /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache
```

If bootloader is unlocked you can also format from `fastboot`

```
fastboot format:ext4 cache
```

---

For further analyzing boot-loop **usb-debugging** is required. On unlocked device you can enable by modifying `default.prop`

- download [ROM](https://download.pixelexperience.org/devices) according to your version
- unpack `boot.img` and extract with [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775)
- modify `ramdisk/default.prop` and repack
- flash `image-new.img` into boot partition

(you can read how it works here)
[Why "adb root" does nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116)

```
  ro.adb.secure=0
  ro.secure=0
  ro.debuggable=1
  persist.service.adb.enable=1
  persist.service.debuggable=1
  persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
```

---

If your device is booting far enough you should be able to capture some log during boot. For details and more information on debugging refer to the `logcat` wiki
[Reading and Writing Logs](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logcat/info)