# How to enable USB debugging from TWRP recovery

Tags: adb, twrp, usb-debugging, broken-screen

I have a android device with dead screen. I have installed TWRP recovery for adb interactions while in recovery. I have lineage os 16.0 (Android 9) on my device. I want to access the device screen via using scrcpy. But I don't have developer mode enabled meaning USB debugging is not enabled.

**How do I enable USB debugging while in TWRP recovery?**

Host device will be windows PC with ADB installed.

I have seen some online guide as in how to push RSA key. from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178911/how-to-authorize-and-accept-adb-rsa-key-with-broken-touch-screen-on-android. It says I should use

`cd ~/.android` then
`adb push adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

Is this still applied in Android 9 or lineage os 16.0? Since this guide is little dated.

Note: I search for simmilar topic and all the answers are about how to back up the phone not how to enable USB debugging. This is not what I want. All I want to know is how to enable USB debugging through editting files while in recovery adb.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116 add entry in */data/local.prop*. before using *scrcpy* delete other *adb.exe* which comes bundled (or set environment variable *'ADB=path/to/adb.exe'*). concatenate files *'cat adbkey.pub >> adb_keys'* instead of adb push