# Can't root ADB Daemon

Tags: bash, root-access, adb

I have a rooted MediaTek Infinix Hot 5 (X559C).
It was **Android 7.0 Nougat** before.
And I don't remember correctly, but I think `adb root` was working.

But after installing custom Android 8.1 Oreo XOS ROM and rooting with [Magisk](https://magiskmanager.com/), the ADB shell works as root correctly. I can execute

```
C:\Users\user> ADB Shell
Infinix-X559C:/ $ su
Infinix-X559C:/ #
```

and it gives me # and no problem with that.
But when I try `adb push/pull`, it gives me an error with permission denied.
When I execute `adb root`, it gives me this output

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I tried [Adbd Insecure](https://xdaforums.com/t/2014-11-10-root-adbd-insecure-v2-00.1687590/), but nothing changed.
I also tried adb-root Magisk modules, but they run with arm64 and aarch64 only, and my phone is 32-bit armeabi-v7a, so they corrupt. Connection with PC makes my phone unreadable on PC until I remove them from Magisk Manager.

And I really want to know what **production builds** is and how to patch adb daemon.

Comment: Production build means certain build/compile flags when building the Android ROM that are designed to generate an image installed on a phone to be sold (instead of a debug build). In such builds adb daemon for example drops root permissions as part of the startup process so calls like `adb root` will not work. To my knowledge dropping permissions is done by Linux C commands like `setuid`. So if you want to patch adb you have to disassemble adb daemon binary find that call, overwrite it with `nop` or smgh. Like that and then write the patched adb daemon binary.

Comment: [Why does "adb root" do nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "adb root" do nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213116/why-does-adb-root-do-nothing)